# Do I have to wrap multiclass SVM in OneVsRestClassifier()?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, multiclass-classification

I am using an SVM for mulitclass classification between 3 labels **(1,0,-1)**. I thought this could simply be done by using `SVC(decision_function_shape = 'ovr')` in my model. I have only just discovered that there exists an Sklearn package that works as follows:
 `sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier(estimator, n_jobs=-1)`

So my question is, what is the difference between the `OneVsRestClassifier()` and `SVC(decision_function_shape = 'ovr')`. And in what scenario could one method or the other yield better accuracy?

The current code for my project is as follows:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

    pipe = Pipeline([('sc', preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()), 
                 ('SVM', svm.SVC(decision_function_shape = 'ovr', kernel = 'poly'))])

    candidate_parameters = [{'SVM__C': [1], 
                        'SVM__gamma': [1] }]
clf = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipe, param_grid = candidate_parameters, cv = 5, n_jobs = -1)
```